# Does the Knowledge argument refute physicalism?

Tags: argumentation, consciousness, knowledge, physicalism

Is there any research that disproves Jackson's three premises?

Is there any research which argues that Mary does not learn all the physical facts whilst in the room, because experience itself produces a physical fact? This is the argument I want to make but as of yet cannot find any support for my claim. Is it not worth pursuing?

Comment: SEP has an [article on Jackson's argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge) with a long list of objections and lengthy bibliography. On many accounts it is invalid so there is not even a need to "disprove" the premises. Of the latter, "Mary lacks factual knowledge before release" is most often disputed.